# What am I missing in this kubernetes RBAC setup?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, k8s-serviceaccount, k8s-rolebinding

I want to run a pod that listens for updates to endpoint lists (I'm not yet ready to adopt the alpha-level feature of endpoint sets, but I'll expand to that eventually.)

I have this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
    "syscall"

    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/runtime"
    "k8s.io/client-go/informers"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/rest"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache"
)

func ReadKubeConfig() (*rest.Config, *kubernetes.Clientset, error) {
    config, err := rest.InClusterConfig()
    if err != nil {
            return nil, nil, err
    }
    clients, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
            return nil, nil, err
    }
    return config, clients, nil
}

func main() {
    _, cs, err := ReadKubeConfig()
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("could not create Clientset: %s\n", err)
            os.Exit(1)
    }
    factory := informers.NewSharedInformerFactory(cs, 0)
    ifmr := factory.Core().V1().Endpoints().Informer()
    stop := make(chan struct{})
    ifmr.AddEventHandler(cache.ResourceEventHandlerFuncs{
            AddFunc: func(next interface{}) {
                    fmt.Printf("AddFunc(%v)\n", next)
            },
            UpdateFunc: func(prev, next interface{}) {
                    fmt.Printf("UpdateFunc(%v, %v)\n", prev, next)
            },
            DeleteFunc: func(prev interface{}) {
                    fmt.Printf("DeleteFunc(%v)\n", prev)
            },
    })
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
            defer runtime.HandleCrash()
            ifmr.Run(stop)
            wg.Done()
    }()
    ch := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(ch, os.Interrupt)
    signal.Notify(ch, os.Signal(syscall.SIGTERM))
    signal.Notify(ch, os.Signal(syscall.SIGHUP))
    sig := <-ch
    fmt.Printf("Received signal %s\n", sig)
    close(stop)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

I get this error when deploying and running:

```
kubeendpointwatcher.go:55: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: endpoints is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:eng:default" cannot list resource "endpoints" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

I have the following role and role binding defined and deployed to the "eng" namespace:

```
watch_endpoints$ kubectl -n eng get role mesh-endpoint-read -o yaml

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-07-08T19:59:20Z"
  name: mesh-endpoint-read
  namespace: eng
  resourceVersion: "182975428"
  selfLink: /apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/eng/roles/mesh-endpoint-read
  uid: fcadcc2a-19d0-4d6e-bee1-78413f51b91b
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - endpoints
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

I have the following rolebinding:

```
watch_endpoints$ kubectl -n eng get rolebinding mesh-endpoint-read -o yaml | sed -e 's/^/    /g'

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-07-08T19:59:20Z"
  name: mesh-endpoint-read
  namespace: eng
  resourceVersion: "182977845"
  selfLink: /apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/eng/rolebindings/mesh-endpoint-read
  uid: 705a3e50-2a73-47ed-aa62-0ea48f3493ee
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: mesh-endpoint-read
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: default
```

You will note that I apply it to both the `default` namespace and the `eng` namespace serviceaccount named `default` although the error message seems to indicate that it is indeed running in the `default` serviceaccount in the `eng` namespace.

I have previously used Role and RoleBinding and ServiceAccount objects that work as expected, so I don't understand why this doesn't work. What am I missing?

For testing/reproduction purposes, I run this program by doing `kubectl cp` of a built binary (cgo off) into a container created with `kubectl -n eng create deplpoy` with a vanilla `ubuntu` image running `/bin/sh -c sleep 999999999`, and then executing a /bin/bash shell in that pod-container.

Comment: you have created `role` and `rolebinding` for `eng` namespace. However, as per the error message you are doing query for `endpoints` at the `"cluster"` scope.  either try to limit your query to `eng` namespace or use `clusterrole/bindings`  ---this is a guess, not an answer.hope it help.

Comment: That is exactly the answer!
Updating my `Role` to a `ClusterRole` and my `RoleBinding` to a `ClusterRoleBinding` makes the informer work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created `role` and `rolebinding` for `eng` namespace. However, as per the error message:

```
kubeendpointwatcher.go:55: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: endpoints is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:eng:default" cannot list resource "endpoints" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

you are doing query for endpoints at the "`cluster`" scope. Either try to limit your query to eng namespace or use `clusterrole`/`clusterbindings`

Error message provide hint(`system:serviceaccount:eng:default`)that `serviceaccount` running in `eng` namespace, whose name is `default` does not have permission to query `ep` at cluster scope.

**To validate this**, you can run two `curl` calls, first `exec` into the pod using the same `sa` and then run the following for `eng` namespace and later try it on other namespaces.

```
curl -v --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods
```

Comment: To add some color: This was indeed the problem. The reason I used a ClusterRole was that I was using a SharedInformer, which by default does all namespaces. But I only need a single namespace, so using a regular Informer, and a per-namespace Role, was the right solution in my case.